# API results not displayed on startup

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making an app that gets information from coindesks API that responds a JSON, I parse it, and it displays the current bitcoin price index, chart name, etc.. I made a NetworkingManager singleton class, where I make a GET request using the AlamoFire pod, everything there works fine, here's the NetworkingManager code:

```
static let shared = NetworkManager()

let baseURL = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"

var btcEUR : String = ""
var btcGBP : String = ""
var btcUSD : String = ""

var eurSymbol : String = ""
var gbpSymbol : String = ""
var usdSymbol : String = ""

var chartName : String = ""
var timeUpdated : String = ""


private init() {
    getBitcoinData(url: baseURL)
}

func getBitcoinData(url: String) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print("Sucess! Got the bitcoin price data")
                let responseJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                self.updateBitcoinData(bitcoinJSON : responseJSON)
            }
            else{
                print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            }
    }
}

func updateBitcoinData(bitcoinJSON: JSON){
    print("Parsing the JSON")
    self.btcUSD =  bitcoinJSON["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"].string!
    self.btcGBP =  bitcoinJSON["bpi"]["GBP"]["rate"].string!
    self.btcEUR =  bitcoinJSON["bpi"]["EUR"]["rate"].string!

    self.usdSymbol = bitcoinJSON["bpi"]["USD"]["symbol"].string!.html2String
    self.gbpSymbol = bitcoinJSON["bpi"]["GBP"]["symbol"].string!.html2String
    self.eurSymbol = bitcoinJSON["bpi"]["EUR"]["symbol"].string!.html2String

    self.chartName = bitcoinJSON["chartName"].string!
    self.timeUpdated = self.convertUTCDateToLocalDate(dateToConvert: bitcoinJSON["time"]["updated"].string!)
    print("JSON finished parsing")
}

func convertUTCDateToLocalDate(dateToConvert:String) -> String {
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = "MMM  dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
    let convertedDate = format.date(from: dateToConvert)
    format.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    format.dateFormat = "MMM  dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ"
    let localDateStr = format.string(from: convertedDate!)
    return localDateStr
}

func getEurBTC() -> String {
    return btcEUR
}

func getGbpBTC() -> String {
    return btcGBP
}

func getUsdBTC() -> String {
    return btcUSD
}

func getEurSymbol() -> String {
    return eurSymbol
}

func getGbpSymbol() -> String {
    return gbpSymbol
}

func getUsdSymbol() -> String {
    return usdSymbol
}

func getChartName() -> String {
    return chartName
}

func getTimeUpdated() -> String {
    return timeUpdated
}
```

The problem I am having is that on startup in the VC class, I want the app to already display the user the bitcoin price, chartName, etc.. But if I try to add the updateBitcoinData() function in the viewDidLoad or viewWillLoad, on startup they seem to be empty Strings, as if the NetworkingManager class failed to do its job and did not assign the parsed JSON values to the needed variables, BUT if I start using the pickerView, it starts showing my parsed data.

Here is a GIF that shows my problem: https://giphy.com/gifs/7Tf2jALO7YF6eE8jCA.

Here's the VC class:

```
let NetworkingHelper = NetworkManager.shared

let currencyArray = ["USD", "GBP", "EUR" ]
var currencySelected = ""

var USDBTC: String = ""
var GBPBTC: String = ""
var EURBTC: String = ""

var chart : String = ""
var time : String = ""


//Pre-setup IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var bitcoinPriceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currencyPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var chartName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeUpdated: UILabel!

@IBAction func exchangeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let calculatorvc = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC")
    self.present(calculatorvc,animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    updateBitcoinData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currencyPicker.delegate = self
    currencyPicker.dataSource = self
}


//MARK: - Pickerview
/***************************************************************/

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    currencySelected = currencyArray[row]
    let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: currencySelected, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])

    return myTitle
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return currencyArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return currencyArray[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    currencySelected = currencyArray[row]
    updateBitcoinData()
    switch currencySelected {
    case "USD":
        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = USDBTC
    case "GBP":
        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = GBPBTC
    case "EUR":
        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = EURBTC
    default:
        bitcoinPriceLabel.text = USDBTC

    }
}

//MARK: - Assigning the view
/***************************************************************/

func updateBitcoinData() {
    bitcoinPriceLabel.text = NetworkManager.shared.getUsdSymbol() + NetworkManager.shared.getUsdBTC()
    chartName.text = NetworkManager.shared.getChartName()
    timeUpdated.text = NetworkManager.shared.getTimeUpdated()
    USDBTC = NetworkManager.shared.getUsdSymbol() + NetworkManager.shared.getUsdBTC()
    GBPBTC = NetworkManager.shared.getGbpSymbol() + NetworkManager.shared.getGbpBTC()
    EURBTC = NetworkManager.shared.getEurSymbol() + NetworkManager.shared.getEurBTC()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your data isn't present by the time you want to update your labels. Insert another `print("something")` in `updateBitcoinData()` and see if it gets called before your prints in the Alamofire request.

Simplest solution would be to register your ViewController for a custom `Notification` that gets emitted by your NetworkManager, when the response of your request returned the data. You could also write a function with an completion handler, which gets called when the data is received.

**Notification solution**

In your ViewController class implement:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    deinit() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ...
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(bitcoinDataReceived(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ReceivedBitcoinData"), object: nil)
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    @objc func bitcoinDataReceived(_ notification: Notification) {
        updateBitcoinData()
    }
}
```

And in your NetworkManager class:

```
class NetworkManager {
    // ...
    func getBitcoinData(url: String) {

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    print("Sucess! Got the bitcoin price data")
                    let responseJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    self.updateBitcoinData(bitcoinJSON : responseJSON)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.init("ReceivedBitcoinData"), object: nil)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            }
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

You could also write an extension for `Notification.Name` to avoid not receiving Notifications because of typos.

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let ReceivedBitcoinData = Notification.Name.init("ReceivedBitcoinData")
}
```

Example usage with extension:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ReceivedBitcoinData, object: nil)
```

Comment: You are correct! Although I would like to know how can I fix this with the Notifcation emitter or something else you've mentioned?

Comment: I added an example how to use Notifications. **Important:** Don't forget to remove your ViewController as Observer in `deinit()`, otherwise you could experience a NULL pointer exception ;)

Comment: Also keep in my mind, that Notifications get delivered on the thread they were posted. If you want to update your UI after async operations, post your Notifications on main thread or switch to main thread in your target method.